# Azure SQL: Is it possible to use the view from another database?

Tags: sql, azure, view

Being new to Azure SQL, I am already successfully `JOIN`ing my table with the table from the other database (by defining the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` and the related things). However, some queries contain *views* from the other database, not the tables. How can I join my table with that *external* view? Is it possible at all? Or do I have to copy the code from the remote view and work directly with the external tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `create external table` you can access a table or view :

take a look at
https://medium.com/@fbeltrao/access-another-database-in-azure-sql-1afc526b7ad4